# IfError function in VBA not returning 0

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA function is not returning a "0" on error (ie when `-` does not exist within the string):

```
Function check(input1 As Range) As Variant
check = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Search("-",             input1.Cells(1).Value), 0)
End Function
```

Is there an explanation and an alternative?

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
 WorksheetFunction.Search("-", input1.Cells(1).Value)
```

will raise a VBA run-time error if the value being tested doesn't contain "-".  You cannot suppress this run-time error using `WorksheetFunction.IfError`

If you want to do something like this then you can use

```
Application.Search()
```

instead of

```
[Application.]WorksheetFunction.Search()
```

Without the `WorksheetFunction` qualifier, Search() will *return* an error value on no match, which you can check with `IfError()`, or the VBA equivalent `IsError()`

```
Function check(input1 As Range) As Variant
    Dim m
    m = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Search("-", _
                                      input1.Cells(1).Value), 0)

    check = WorksheetFunction.IfError(m, 0)
    'or
    'check = IIf(IsError(m), 0, m)
End Function
```

As @ExcelHero points out though, VBA has `Instr()` which you can use to get the same result with no need for error checking.

Comment: ++ Going the extra mile to actually answer OP's question `Is there an explanation and an alternative?` :)

Answer (score 2):

`IFERROR` is best used on the worksheet side, not in VBA.

In your scenario the most straightforward alternative is this:

```
Function check(input1 As Range) As Variant
    check = InStr(input1, "-")
End Function
```